# Problems with Pygame on MAC OS X

Tags: python, bash, macos, python-2.7, pygame

I am having trouble setting up Pygame on my MAC. Here are my specifications: OS X El Capitan 10.11.4. Whenever I run a file with import pygame I get the following error message in terminal:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

If I try to install pygame from bitbucket that the directions, which I am following told me to do, I get the following message:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip3: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Again, that message appears when I run the following command, in terminal:

```
enter code here pip3 install --user hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

I have tried Youtube videos and stack overflow but nothing seems to help me. I believe, but I am not sure, that I am still pointing to python 2.7 and I have no idea how to fix that. I believe I am using python 3.4. I find problems similar to mine but not sure exactly what to do. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: You can tell which version of python you're using by typing in "python --version" in a terminal and if you need to change the version of python you can change which installation of python your $PATH is currently pointing to.

Comment: Yes, when I type in python --version I get Python 2.7.10 which is not what I use. I think my question is now-How do I change which installation of python your $path is currently point to? That is what I need to do but have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the information at this site worked: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install

Answer (score 0):

Note, I'm not currently on a mac so I'm doing kind of from memory and what I assume should work so some of this might be different for you.

open terminal and type:

```
which python3
```

Copy the value of what the which command returns.
Open up your ~/.bash_profile using a text editor, I think you can just type (but not sure)

```
edit ~/.bash_profile
```

and you can add these two lines into your bash profile:

```
PATH="[Replace me with what the which command returned]:${PATH}" 
export PATH
```

save and then in your terminal window you can type:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $PATH
python --version
```

to verify that it's picked up your changes.

A few caveats I can think of are compatibility between things using python 2.x and 3.x, and this could break existing programs, so if you need to change back for whatever reason just delete the lines you added into your bash profile.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but now when ever I type in commands in terminal I get this message: -bash: which: command not found
-bash: sed: command not found Do you know how to fix this? I have to open bash back back up but it won't let me

Comment: That sounds strange to me, especially the sed portion, maybe something broke when you appended the new python location to your path. In anycase, to undo the changes you will need to open up your ~/.bash_profile, probably using the mac file explorer. Because the file starts with a ., you will have to enable seeing hidden files as well if you haven't already. It will most likely be in a location such as /Users/MyUserName/.bash_profile. Open it and simply remove what you added to bring it back to its original state.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the problem by finding a post on apple support. I actually found almost nothing on the net about this issue! Quite frustrating! But the Apple guide helped but reset a lot of things for me in terminal! I still have yet to fix my pygame issue!